# socket implementation in scapy

Tags: sockets, networking, scapy

I have an application that communicates with a server using TCP, I'm trying to impersonate that server and communicate with my app.

I've also done mitm to redirect the app traffic to my computer.
The problem is that I can't use sockets in python because the IP would be my IP and not the server's so I've tried to do it in scapy to spoof the source IP but then I don't have the socket, easy to use API.

There are any socket modules written in scapy or any built-in functions/classes in the scapy module that allows you to use a socket-like API that handles the TCP communication?
Or alternatively, use the socket module in python and spoof the source IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to implement it myself, I started making the class of socket in python, it works but it's not perfect.

```
from scapy.all import *    

class socket(object):
def __init__(self, src_ip, dst_ip, port):
    self.src_ip = src_ip
    self.dst_ip = dst_ip
    self.port = port

    self._seq = 10000
    self._ack = 0
    self.dport = None


def handshake(self):
    #print self.src_ip, self.dst_ip
    syn = sniff(count=1, lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(IP) and x.haslayer(TCP) and x[IP].dst == self.src_ip and x[IP].src == self.dst_ip and x[TCP].dport == self.port)[0]
    self.dport = syn[TCP].sport
    syn_ack = IP(src = self.src_ip, dst = self.dst_ip) / TCP(flags = 'SA', seq = 20000, ack = syn[TCP].seq + 1, sport = self.port, dport = syn[TCP].sport)
    send(syn_ack)
    self._ack = syn_ack[TCP].ack


def recv(self):
    push = sniff(count=1, lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(IP) and x.haslayer(TCP) and x[IP].dst == self.src_ip and x[IP].src == self.dst_ip and x[TCP].dport == self.port and
    x[TCP].flags == 24)[0]

    #self._ack += len(push[TCP].load)

    #pack = IP(src = self.src_ip, dst = self.dst_ip) / TCP(flags = 'A', seq = self._seq, ack = self._ack, sport = 8070, dport = push[TCP].sport)
    #send(pack)

    # saves last packet's seq, ack and length of data
    a, b, c = push[TCP].seq, push[TCP].ack, len(push[Raw].load)

    self._seq = b
    self._ack = a + c

    pack = IP(src = self.src_ip, dst = self.dst_ip) / TCP(flags = 'A', seq = self._seq, ack = self._ack, sport = self.port, dport = push[TCP].sport)
    send(pack)


    return push[Raw].load


def send(self, data):
    pack = IP(src = self.src_ip, dst = self.dst_ip) / TCP(flags = 24, seq = self._seq, ack = self._ack, sport = self.port, dport = self.dport) / data
    send(pack)


def fin(self):
    fin_ack = sniff(count=1, lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(IP) and x.haslayer(TCP) and x[IP].dst == self.src_ip and x[IP].src == self.dst_ip and x[TCP].dport == self.port and
    x[TCP].flags == 17)[0]

    a, b = fin_ack[TCP].seq, fin_ack[TCP].ack
    pack = IP(src = self.src_ip, dst = self.dst_ip) / TCP(flags = 17, seq = b, ack = a + 1, sport = self.port, dport = self.dport)

    send(pack)
```

You can follow this module for future releases in my github: 
https://github.com/dindibo/Scapy-socket